# jQuery Retrieve Specific Item from UL not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have a dropdownlist and an unordered list:

```
<select id="MySelect">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<ul id="MyUL"></ul>
```

My dropdownlist is using [Select2](https://select2.org/).

When a user selects an option using the dropdownlist, that option is being populated into the unordered list along with a button beside it.

**jQuery**

```
$("#MySelect").on("select2:select", function(evt){
    $("#MyUL").append("<li>" + evt.params.data.text + "<input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs remove-button' style='margin-left:56%;' value='x' /></li>");

    testButton(); // explained below
});
```

Since the user has the ability to add things to the list, I want them to be able to remove items from the list as well, and that is where I'm stuck.

I have a function called `testButton`

```
function testButton() {
    $(".remove-button").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).parent().text()); // testing this out
    });
}
```

What happens is, when the user selects 2 options from the dropdownlist and those options are put into the unordered list.. if I click on the first element's button I get alerted twice.. and so on and so on...

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xxbpg44/).

How do I remove the `li` element that I clicked the button in the same `li` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Every time you're changing the value of the first select, your triggering the function `testButton` which will bind the click event on the `.remove-buttons` even if they have an event previously.

### Solution

Instead of binding the click on the `.remove-buttons` every time the user change the select, you could bind it on a parent element to have the event bound to dynamically created elements.

To do so, move your `testButton` function outside of your `select2:select` event.

```
testButton();

$("#MySelect").on("select2:select", function(evt){
    $("#MyUL").append("<li>" + evt.params.data.text + "<input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs remove-button' style='margin-left:56%;' value='x' /></li>");
});
```

Then update your function to bind the event on the body.

```
function testButton() {
    $("body").on("click", ".remove-button", function() {
        alert($(this).parent().text());
    });
}
```

### Demo

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xxbpg44/17/

Comment: Ok, I knew it wasn't in the right place being in the `select` event.. but if I moved it outside of that.. then it would've been in the `$(document).ready(...)`.. and nothing worked then because on page load.. there are zero elements with the class `.remove-button` because those element are dynamically loaded.. but I never thought to use `$("body")`.. which is really where I didn't know what to do.  So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your event is being called multiple times because each time you create a button, you are creating a new event binding for all `.remove-button` elements.

The following code uses a few objects and removes the necessity for `testButton` altogether:

```
$("#MySelect").select2();

$("#MySelect").on("select2:select", function(evt) {

  // Creating jQuery objects separately
  var item = $("<li>" + evt.params.data.text + "</li>");
  var button = $("<input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs remove-button' style='margin-left:56%;' value='x' />");

  // Append button to item and item to UL
  item.append(button);
  $("#MyUL").append(item);

  // Creating event for button
  button.on("click", function() {
    $(this).unbind();          // Unbinding event to prevent clogging
    $(this).parent().detach(); // Removing list item from its parent
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `unbind` the previous click event before adding the new one:

```
function testButton() {
    $(".remove-button").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).parent().text());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why this happens?**

- Because You are calling event function each time select2 change event occurs. Its bad practise to do so.

*First remove call to testButton from select2 select event.Otherwise every time select2 changes duplicate events will create and hence you will see those many alerts*

```
$("#MySelect").on("select2:select", function(evt){
  $("#MyUL").append("<li>" + evt.params.data.text + "<input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs remove-button' style='margin-left:56%;' value='x' /></li>");

//testButton(); remove this.
});
```

**--Write remove event like this i.e directly on document.This will ensure that dynamically created element can be bind with events**

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-button", function() {
  alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```